# OSError: SavedModel file does not exist

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I saved a model as trained_model.h5 and loaded the model in different file was easily able to run it, it was working until today, it has started showing error

```
OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at: C:\Users\harsh\AppData\Local\Temp\tfhub_modules\602d30248ff7929470db09f7385fc895e9ceb4c0\{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}
```

[directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o74Yq.png)

I load the model using

```
model = tf.keras.models.load_model(('trained_model.h5'), custom_objects={'KerasLayer':hub.KerasLayer})
```

why is it showing error today and was working before ?

Comment: Please try again by providing the full path of where this `trained_model.h5` model is saved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just deleted all the Temp files and it has started working fine again, I think it is some Windows flaw.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `.h5` extension use `.pd`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).